# How to say that the locals take their time to help foreigners?

Tags: vocabulary

I can't think of a nice way to express the idea of "the locals take their time to help foreigners."

Expressions that come to mind:
devote their time
use their time
or take their time -- I tend to gravitate to this one -- prob. because of my mother tongue

How would you say it?

Comment: Asking for phrases to be improved is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a tiny change, but it makes all the difference...

> 1: *They take time to welcome visitors*  (OR *...take **the** time*; sometimes ***make** time*)
> They're ***helpful*** - they ***give up / sacrifice*** their time to help

> 2: They take **their** time welcoming visitors
> They're ***unhelpful*** - they ***dawdle around*** and only ***slowly / reluctantly*** offer help

---

Here are the relevant dictionary definitions...

**take the time** [to do something]  ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-the-time-to))
to spend enough time to do something well or carefully
*She didn’t even take the time to say goodbye.*

**take one's time** [doing something]  ([Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/take-ones-time))
to be slow or leisurely; dawdle
*Speed was important here, but he just took his time.*

...where it's worth pointing out that if no determiner *(the, one's, their)* is present, #1 is the "default". Also, the choice of infinitive or continuous verb for the "complement" (identifying the relevant activity) is *usually* as given above - but the *opposite* choice is perfectly valid.